# Is it possible to constrain a swift generic type to be any closure

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

While it is possible to define a closure signature and use that as the concrete type of a generic type, is it possible to constrain the possible types of the generic to closures only - so the user couldn't set it to be a string for example. Something like the following:

```
class MyClass <T where T:Closure> {
    init(closure:T) {
        closure()
    }
}
```

So the user can pass any closure they want (that accepts any parameters, return values, throws status etc) but it has to be a closure.

Comment: What would you do with an arbitrary closure? Are there reflection facilities that would allow you to inspect/call it in Swift?

Comment: For example if MyClass executes a different closure that I define which accepts T as an argument. The user can pass in their code for what should be executed in that closure, and then call the closure T that they have defined, passing in their own arguments.

Comment: @Bill If you could constrain the generic type to some sort of Closure protocol (presumably with some way to access the argument and result associated types), you could build a better weak observer/event classes (see http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/05/swift-events.html for an example).

You could also wrap closures in generics (for whatever reason) and ensure it's actually a closure type being wrapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare 2 generic parameters, one for parameter type, one for return type:

```
class MyClass <Arg, Result> {
    let closure: Arg -> Result

    init(closure: Arg -> Result) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    func call(arg: Arg) -> Result {
        return self.closure(arg)
    }
}

let obj = MyClass { (a: Int, b: String) -> String in
    return "a: \(a), b: \(b)"
}

obj.call((42, "Hello"))  // -> "a: 42, b: Hello"
```

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for but it seems like it is the solution.